# mysql (5.5.) cmd unresponsive when selecting a huge db

Tags: mysql, import, command-line

I had initiated on Friday night a huge (~800G) dump from my machine to a remote host;

Today, (although the command does not seem to have returned yet), I am able to log in to the machine and `mysql` cmd but when selecting this db, the shell becomes unresponsive:

```
mysql> use my-huge-db;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -

_
```

How to debug this?

Is there a way to check if the import is still taking place?

Comment: follow the instructions on turning off autocompletion. Then look at 'SHOW PROCESSLIST' to see what its doing.

Answer (score 1):

The client message should read (emphasis mine)

> Reading table information for completion of table and column names You
>   can turn off this feature **to get a quicker startup with -A**

where "-A" is the shortcut for --no-auto-rehash.

By Default, the MySQL client will, on connection, run queries on the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to discover

- all the tables in the current database
- all the columns for all the tables found

This is to support "auto completion", so that a human can type

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLO<TAB>
```

and the tool will then expand the query text to

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
```

This feature is very costly when the database is big, and it should be disabled to improve connection time.

See the reference manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_auto-rehash